# Where is the infite loop and how to fix it?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

This is a practice quiz question for a course I'm taking. Need to fix the code.

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False


print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Comment: Did you run it? What did it output? Did you run through the code by hand on the input that doesn't terminate? What did you learn?

Comment: Error message when I run it as is "Evaluation took more than 5 seconds to complete.  Please try again with a simpler expression."

Comment: find out how to run python on your local machine so you can debug it.

Answer (score 1):

for `n = 0`, each cycle n is 0, and it will run into next cycle

```
  while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n / 2
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Figured it out, need to next the code into "if n == 0:
    return False"

Comment: 0 is not a power of 2. Also, 2, 4, and 8 do not trigger infinite loops.